# How to find max() in an Array in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

How do I search 3 items in an array for the highest number?

**JavaScript Example that works:**

```
function knapsackLight(value1, weight1, value2, weight2, maxW) {
    return Math.max(
        maxW >= weight1 && value1,
        maxW >= weight2 && value2,
        maxW >= weight1 + weight2 && value1 + value2
    );
}
```

**PHP Example that does not work:**

```
function knapsackLight($value1, $weight1, $value2, $weight2, $maxW) {
    $results[0] = $maxW >= $weight1 && $value1;
    $results[1] = $maxW >= $weight2 && $value2;
    $results[2] = $maxW >= $weight1 + $weight2 && $value1 + $value2;
    return max($results[0], $results[1], $results[2]);
}
```

***Test 1:***

**Input**

value1: 10
weight1: 5
value2: 6
weight2: 4
maxW: 8

**Expected Output:**
10

***Test 2:***

**Input:**

value1: 10
weight1: 5
value2: 6
weight2: 4
maxW: 9

**Expected Output:**
16

***Test 3***

Input:
value1: 5
weight1: 3
value2: 7
weight2: 4
maxW: 6

**Expected Output:** 7

**Example**

For value1 = 10, weight1 = 5, value2 = 6, weight2 = 4, and maxW = 8, the output should be
knapsackLight(value1, weight1, value2, weight2, maxW) = 10.

*You can only carry the first item.*

For value1 = 10, weight1 = 5, value2 = 6, weight2 = 4, and maxW = 9, the output should be
knapsackLight(value1, weight1, value2, weight2, maxW) = 16.

*You're strong enough to take both of the items with you.*

For value1 = 5, weight1 = 3, value2 = 7, weight2 = 4, and maxW = 6, the output should be
knapsackLight(value1, weight1, value2, weight2, maxW) = 7.

*You can't take both items, but you can take any of them.*

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do by providing sample input and output data.

Comment: @Script47 done.

Comment: Can you not use `array_filter` instead?

Comment: How does the second example become 16?

Comment: @Andreas see edited post. Knapsack Light coding example is from website CodeSignal. https://app.codesignal.com/arcade/code-arcade/at-the-crossroads/r9azLYp2BDZPyzaG2/

Comment: Why is it hard to understand I have 4 answers of people who understand the question?

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, using `&&` will evaulate the expression to a boolean `true` or `false`, so this approach will make every value in `$results` a boolean.

One alternative is to use the boolean results in a ternary operator to assign the `$valueX` or `null` into the array, or you can use `array_filter()`.

Using `array_filter()`, it can look like this

```php
function knapsackLight($value1, $weight1, $value2, $weight2, $maxW) {
    $result = [];
    $result[] = ['weight' => $weight1, 'value' => $value1];
    $result[] = ['weight' => $weight2, 'value' => $value2];
    $result[] = ['weight' => $weight1 + $weight2, 'value' => $value1 + $weight2];

    $result = array_filter($result, function($v) use ($maxW) {
       return $v['weight'] <= $maxW;
    });

    return max(array_column($result, 'value'));
}
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/EXpjC

If you want to go with ternary operators, it would look like this

```php
function knapsackLight($value1, $weight1, $value2, $weight2, $maxW) {
    $results[0] = $maxW >= $weight1 && $value1 ? $value1 : null;
    $results[1] = $maxW >= $weight2 && $value2 ? $value2 : null;
    $results[2] = $maxW >= $weight1 + $weight2 && $value1 + $value2 ? $value1 + $value2 : null;
    return max($results[0], $results[1], $results[2]);
}
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/0EBlC

Comment: Not sure why you have the second part of `$weight1 && $value1` (etc.)

Comment: It seemed to me that OP wanted to only use non-zero values, so that'd be a "check" of sorts that its a valid non-zero integer - it's based on the code in the original question. Though, personally, I'd prefer using `array_filter()` over the latter example.

Comment: Great examples except it should be 0 instead of null

Answer (score 1):

The operator `&&` in php doesn't behave like in js. It returns a boolean since it's a logical operator. The closest you can get is a ternary operator.

```
function knapsackLight($value1, $weight1, $value2, $weight2, $maxW) {
    $results[0] = $maxW >= $weight1 ? $value1 : 0;
    $results[1] = $maxW >= $weight2 ? $value2 : 0;
    $results[2] = $maxW >= $weight1 + $weight2 ? $value1 + $value2 : 0;
    return max($results);
}
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/nMc7e)

Comment: It should return 0 instead of null.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is caused by the difference in the behaviour of the boolean operator of JavaScript and PHP.

- In JS, the `&&` operator return the original value of the operant, without converting the final results to boolean. For example, `true && 3` returns `3`.
- In PHP, the `&&` operator always return boolean value. For example, `true && 3` returns `true`.

Your equivalent implementation in PHP should be

```
function knapsackLight($value1, $weight1, $value2, $weight2, $maxW) {
    $results[0] = $maxW >= $weight1 ? $value1 : 0;
    $results[1] = $maxW >= $weight2 ? $value2 : 0;
    $results[2] = $maxW >= $weight1 + $weight2 ? ($value1 + $value2): 0;
    return max($results[0], $results[1], $results[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little improve from @N. Alcuino's answer:

```
function knapsackLight($value1, $weight1, $value2, $weight2, $maxW) {
   $results[0] = ($maxW >= $weight1) ? $value1 : false;
   $results[1] = ($maxW >= $weight2) ? $value2 : false;
   $results[2] = ($maxW >= ($weight1 + $weight2)) ? ($value1 + $value2) : false;
   return max($results);
}
```

[Test](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8123a91e780b25abab756fba5ff9f312f9fc4a63)

Comment: It should return 0 instead of false